# Gurobi Python: show n best Solutions of MILP

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to not only get the optimal solution of my MIP, but the 5 best solutions. I know, how to get Gurobi to save the 5 best solutions but I dont know how I can access them like I do with the optimal solution (see below), specifically the values of the 2 decision variables `x[i,j]` and `y[j]`

```js
model.setParam(GRB.Param.PoolSearchMode, 2)
model.SetParam(GRB.Param.PoolSolutions, 5)

# ..... opt. model

if model.Status == GRB.OPTIMAL:

  for j in jt:
    print ('z[%f] = %f' %(j, y[j].x))
  
  for i in ft:
    for j in jt:
      print ('x[%f,%f] = %f' %(i,j, x[i,j].x))
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: [This: gurobi-docs: retrieving_solutions?](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/refman/retrieving_solutions.html)

Comment: Thanks, the code isn't throwing any errors. I get 5 solutions for my optimization problem. 
However, all solutions are exactly the same, the values of my decision variables don't vary just like the objective value is the same in all 5 solutions. I had to adjust my problem, so that it became an Integer problem (IP). Any idea how i can retrieve the best 5 solutions now?!